# how to remove __iter__ in subclass of iterable class in python

Tags: python, iteration

I want to disable `__iter__` in subclass of tuple. I do it like this:

```
def __iter__(self):
    raise TypeError("'%s' object is not iterable" % self.__class__.__name__)
```

But it seems not the right way. Anyone can help?

Comment: [Barbara, are you there to answer this?](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle)

Comment: Why in *heavens* name do you need this?

Comment: Please don't. But look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1684099/is-it-possible-to-delete-a-method-from-an-object-not-class-in-python

Comment: Why would you want to do this?... it will break expectations and code fairly quickly.

Comment: just want not be able to iterate. I have problem with `'%G' % myinstance`. the subclass have a magic class `__float__` but it doesn't use it.

Comment: @martijn the most appropriate would be NotImplementedError - then at least a programmer can ask "wtf not?" - instead of thinking a debug mission is in order

Comment: @JonClements: Yeah, that one is probably better.

Comment: Because you have a *container*. Why do you have a subclass of tuple that pretends to be a floating point value? Is formatting the only problem? Then use `__format__()` instead.

Comment: Please tell us what you *really* try to do here, and avoid [X-Y problems](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Although it a very questionable thing to do, object-oriented-programming-wise, yes that's the way to do it -- although you might want to raise a more descriptive error type like `NotImplementedError` as Jon suggested. `RuntimeError`, or even derive your own: i.e. `class InexplicablyNotIterableError(Exception)`.